# Allure TeamCity plugin showing empty report

Tags: maven, teamcity, allure

Teamcity running on machine "А". 
Agent running on machine "B". On the same machine ("B") maven is triggering selenium web tests.
There are allure reports as well "mvn clean test site jetty:run" working fine.

I've installed allure teamcity plugin. Added path to allure reports. 
But allure report is empty each time i open it after test finished.

Thanks for Any help & support in advance!

**Allure screenshot:**automated-testing.info//uploads/default/1693/2d09b275384e6800.PNG

**Teamcity screenshot:** http://automated-testing.info//uploads/default/1691/37400f7a5cbe8d2f.PNG

**Teamcity screenshot:** http://automated-testing.info//uploads/default/1692/eb9e8664d8222407.PNG

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <allure.version>1.4.14</allure.version>
    <aspectj.version>1.7.4</aspectj.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>2.45.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
        <version>2.45.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>ru.yandex.qatools.allure</groupId>
        <artifactId>allure-junit-adaptor</artifactId>
        <version>${allure.version}</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.18</version>
            <configuration>
                <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
                <argLine>
                    -javaagent:${settings.localRepository}/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/${aspectj.version}/aspectjweaver-${aspectj.version}.jar
                </argLine>
                <properties>
                    <property>
                        <name>listener</name>
                        <value>ru.yandex.qatools.allure.junit.AllureRunListener</value>
                    </property>
                </properties>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                    <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
                    <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <webAppSourceDirectory>${project.build.directory}/site/allure-maven-plugin</webAppSourceDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<reporting>
    <excludeDefaults>true</excludeDefaults>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>ru.yandex.qatools.allure</groupId>
            <artifactId>allure-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <allureresultsdirectory>${project.build.directory}/allure-results</allureresultsdirectory>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
```

```
[13:13:31][INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[13:13:31][INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[13:13:31][INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[13:13:31][INFO] Total time: 2:10.375s
[13:13:31][INFO] Finished at: Thu Jun 04 15:13:30 EEST 2015
[13:13:31][INFO] Final Memory: 38M/364M
[13:13:31][INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[13:13:31]Process exited with code 0
[13:13:31]Publishing artifacts
[13:13:31]Collecting files to publish: [D:\BuildAgent\temp\buildTmp\.tc-maven-bi\maven-build-info.xml.gz => .teamcity]
[13:13:31]Publishing using [ArtifactsCachePublisher]
[13:13:32]Publishing using [WebPublisher]
[13:13:32]Waiting for 2 service processes to complete
[13:13:32]Allure report generation (8s)
[13:13:32]analyse results pattern [D:\BuildAgent\work\792b367268134f82\automation\target\allure-results]
[13:13:32]analyse results directories []
[13:13:32]prepare allure report directory [D:\BuildAgent\temp\agentTmp\allure]
[13:13:32]prepare report generator with version: 1.4.14
[13:13:32]process tests results to directory [D:\BuildAgent\temp\agentTmp\allure]
[13:13:40]unpack report face to directory [D:\BuildAgent\temp\agentTmp\allure]
[13:13:41]Publishing artifacts (2s)
[13:13:42]Surefire report watcher
[13:13:42]1 report found for paths:
[13:13:42]D:\BuildAgent\work\792b367268134f82\automation\target\surefire-reports\TEST-*.xml
[13:13:42]Successfully parsed
[13:13:44]Publishing internal artifacts
[13:13:45]Sending using ArtifactsCachePublisher
[13:13:45]Sending using WebPublisher
[13:13:46]Build finished
```

Answer (score 1):

```
[13:13:32]analyse results pattern [D:\BuildAgent\work\792b367268134f82\automation\target\allure-results
[13:13:32]analyse results directories []
```

Your results pattern is incorrect that's why Allure can't find directories with XML files generated during test run. Please try `**/allure-results` as specified by default.

Answer (score 0):

1. results directory [**/allure-results] was OK in my setup
2. There was "Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space" error during build, after that I increased PermGen memory in TeamCity agent

Now everything is OK! Thank you